# Extending the behavior of an inherited function in Python

Tags: python, function, inheritance, overriding, decorator

Let's say we have the following classes:

```
class Base(object):

    def load(self):
        # do logic A

        # do logic B

class Child(Base):

    def load(self):
        # do logic C
```

I know decorators can be used to extend function behavior in Python but I don't know how I can apply it in my case.
When `Child's` `load()` is called, how can I get the following code executions in this order?:

```
logic A

logic C

logic B
```

What **I don't** want to do

```
class Base(object)

    def logicA()
       pass

    def logicB()
       pass

    def load()
       pass

class Child(Base):

    def load(self):
        super.logicA()

        # do logic C

        super.logicB()
```

I just want to code up logic C, without having to explicitly call logic A and B

Comment: Split logic A and B in to two different functions?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
class Base(object):

    def load(self):
        print('do logic A')
        print('do logic B')


class Child(Base):

    def load(self):
        super().load()
        print('do logic C')


c = Child()
c.load()
```

This will print:

```
do logic A
do logic B
do logic C
```

The only other way I can think of is this one:

```
class Base(object):

    def load(self):
        print('do logic A')
        self.new_logic() # call new logic from child class, if exist.
        print('do logic B')

    def new_logic(self):
        # overwrite this one in child class 
        pass


class Child(Base):

    def new_logic(self):
        print('do logic C')


c = Child()
c.load()
```

This prints:

```
do logic A
do logic C
do logic B
```

Comment: Close, but I am aiming for logic C to be called before B

Comment: But the thing is, I don't want to explicitly be calling logic A or B...logic C is basically just an extension of the Base load()

Comment: @Unit978 You are saying you want the child function to execute in the middle of the base classes function ?

Comment: Maybe pass a function to perform logic C to the base class function and call it in between  logic A and Logic B?

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to explicitly call anything from the Base class.

Comment: @Unit978 I amended the answer with other possibility.